Access different weights from dict in igraph - python
I'm trying to return the distance between a single node and a list of other nodes using igraph. It works fine when I use a single weight. But I want to add various weights to edges and be able to use a different weighting value in the graph.
works fine with a single weight passed:
nxG = nx.MultiDiGraph()
nxG.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)

g = ig.Graph.from_networkx(nxG)

g.distances(source=nodes, weights='weight')[0]

But, if I add multiple weights to edges as a dict, like below:
{'weight': 1, 'weight2': 5, 'weight3': 10}

I can access them directly through:
print(g.es['weight'][0]['weight2']) = 5

But when I insert the same call into the function, I'm returning an error?
g.distances(source=nodes, weights=g.es['weight'][0]['weight2'])

Out:
TypeError: unhandled type"


You need to pass correct edge attr name to weights params of distances method:
nxG = nx.MultiDiGraph()
nxG.add_edges_from([(0, 1, {'weight': 1, 'weight2': 5, 'weight3': 10})])
g = ig.Graph.from_networkx(nxG)

After this, when you want to use specific weight, you need to use the edge attr directly:
distances = g.distances(source=nodes, weights='weight2')

If you want to use custom weights that arent stored as attribute, you need to pass them directly:
custom_weights = [edge['weight2'] for edge in g.es]
distances = g.distances(source=nodes, weights=custom_weights)

